# How to make Java Script ignore or maintain spaces, not delete them

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, str-replace, spaces

I'm trying to have a function cover a multi-word region with dashes, but not cover the space between the words with a dash in Java Script. So, I basically need JS to ignore the spaces (or maintain then?) but all I've found online is how to remove spaces from a string. If I do that, then there will still be no spaces between the dashes covering the region (though it would technically be the correct length without the space).
This is the function I'm working with for this:
Begin Routine:

```
sentenceList = Sentence.split(",");
 wordNumber = (- 2);
```

Each Frame:

```
var _pj;
function replaceWithdash(sentenceList, currentWordNumber) {
var index, result, word;
result = "";
index = 0;
while ((index < sentenceList.length)) {
    word = sentenceList[index];
    if ((index !== currentWordNumber)) {
          result = ((result + ("-".repeat(word.length))) + " ");  
    } else {
        result = ((result + word) + " ");
    }
    index = (index + 1);
}
return result;
}
```

Regions are separated by the delimiter "," so that multiple words can be included. The variable "word" basically indexes through these regions in the sentence. The function 'replaceWithdash' replaces the 'word' length (total region) with dashes. I don't know how to somehow keep the display as region by region but have the replaceWithdash function ignore or maintain spaces. Input: The dog, ate, the food.
Current display:

```
 ------- --- --------
The dog --- --------
```

Desired display:

```
 --- --- --- --- ----
The dog --- --------
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Please provide sentence input also?

Comment: The sentence input in the csv file would be something like this: The dog, ate, the food. I've also tried using a different delimiter between words like an underscore so that the input is: The_dog,_ate,_the_food. But that doesn't actually solve any issue because JS still reads the underscores as characters.

Comment: So you want `The dog, ate, the food` to be like `--- --- --- --- ----`

Comment: yes, exactly! But i need the display to not be word by word, instead to be region (mulit-word) by region. Messing with the input sentence for replaceWithdash doesn't successfully do this (as in changing delimiters and such), so what I;m trying to do is not have replaceWithdash read the spaces between words as characters and keep them as spaces.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `But i need the display to not be word by word, instead to be region (mulit-word) by region.`?

Comment: what is the `region` here? Dude you need to clarify what exactly do you want? It is so unclear.

Comment: Since this is a self-paced reading experiment, we care about how long participants spend in different word regions of the sentence. These regions can be only one word or multiple words. Here we care about multiple word regions, so when I say region I mean multiple words; when I say words, I mean individual words in the sentence. I need display to seperately show region by region as participants click through the sentences, but I need the dashes that cover those regions to not cover the spaces between the individual words there.

Comment: Ok, I can't understand you. What is the expected output for `"The dog, ate, the food" `? No verbiage, just the output

Comment: Hi, I actually made a different post about this which I think a better and more targeted question, plus I think it's a bit more clear there if you;d like to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67681063/one-index-is-dependent-on-another-index-in-java-script

Comment: Is this what you need? `str.replaceAll(/[^\s,]/g, "-").replaceAll(",","")`

Comment: Is that taking a string and replacing all things with dashes expect for commas and spaces? Sorry , I'm new to this coding language so plain English can be a bit helpful for me!

Comment: @cousin63-lang Pretend that I'm 7 years old and explain (in your question, not as a comment) what you want, with multiple examples of input and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you are looking or, right?

```js
function replaceWithdash(sentenceList, currentWordNumber) {
    const regions = sentenceList.split(",")
    const sigil = regions.map(s => s.replaceAll(/[^\s]/g, "-"))
    if (currentWordNumber !== undefined) {
        sigil.splice(currentWordNumber, 1, regions[currentWordNumber])
    }
    return sigil.join("")
}

str = "The dog, ate, the food"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str))
//"--- --- --- --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 0))
//"The dog --- --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 1))
//"--- --- ate --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 2))
// "--- --- --- the food"
```