# One index is dependent on another index in Java Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, indexing, embedding

I'm making a function for a moving window design self-paced reading experiment where a sentence is input and a function replaces all letters with dashes. The participant then clicks through the sentences, uncovering the first word/region; upon the next click, the second word/region is uncovered and the previous word/region is covered by dashes again and so on until the end of the sentence. Below is my code for a replaceWithdash function in order to achieve this.

```
function replaceWithdash(sentenceList, currentWordNumber) {
var index, result, word, lett, reslett;
result = "";
index = 0;
while ((index < sentenceList.length)) {
    word = sentenceList[index];
    if ((index !== currentWordNumber)) {
          result = ((result + ("-".repeat(word.length))) + " "); 
    } else {
        result = ((result + word) + " ");
    }
    index = (index + 1);
    lett = Sentence.charAt(index);
    reslett = result.charAct(index);
    if (lett === " ") {
        result = (reslett.replace("-"," "));
        } else {
        result = (reslett);
        }
    }
return result;
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the display of the dashed sentence. The first ifelse function basically says that if you're not on the current word, replace the length of the words (separated in 'sentenceList', then defined in 'word') with dashes. If you are on the current word, then just display that word as is. So a word by word display would look like this: Input = The dog ate the food

```
--- --- --- ----
*click*
The --- --- ----
*click*
--- dog --- ----
```

and so on. The problem I face (hence the need for the 'lett' and 'reslett' variables) is that I don't want to display word by word, instead I want to display region by region. These regions can include multiple words. So in the example above, the first *region* would be 'the dog' not just 'the'. In order to separate the string to display correctly on click, I simply changed the input to 'The dog, ate, the food' and made commas a delimiter to separate sentenceList. However, this yields this result:

```
------- --- --------
*click*
The dog --- --------
```

As you can see, the display is correct in that the first region rater than first word is shown but the replaceWithdash function is reading the spaces between words as a character, so the dash display is incorrect and no space is seen (so it looks like there are 3 words in the sentence and not 5). As a way to avoid this, I'm trying to create another if-statement using the variables 'lett' and 'reslett' which pick out a specific index in the raw sentence and in the dashed sentence ('result'). The if-else is meant to say: if the character index in the sentence is a space, then the same character index in the result dashed sentence (since they are the same length) is replaced with a space. If the character is not a space, then just keep it as is in result, i.e. a dash. So, in the sentence above, through charAt(0)-charAt(3), the dashes should remain, but once you hit charAt(4), 'result' should now replace that dash with a space.
I don't know much Java Script besides what I've been teaching myself, so I think my code might be a bit off here because it's not actually working.
The display I need is this:

```
--- --- --- --- ----
*click*
The dog --- --- ----
```

With this code, it just replaces all dashes with spaces (so the display is nothing), so something's wrong here, any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a "raw" string to test with as data.  "Two undefined variables
11 lett
13 lett
12 reslett
14 reslett
16 reslett
Two unused variables
1 _pj
2 replaceWithdash
"

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by a 'raw' string (I'm new to this, sorry). I thought it would just be a sentence like the one I gave "The_dog,_ate,_the_food"?

Comment: Perhaps put that example and how you pass it to the function IN the code which may help add clarity to the question.  What do you mean by "My experiment isn't initializing" - is there an error? if so what is that.  Try to isolate to the one problem you have.

Comment: So, the input is coming from a csv- or more specifically a column of sentences similar to the one in my comment above. I should've clarified, but this code is from a code component on the experiment builder Psychopy3 ran online on Pavlovia. When I say the experiment isn't initializing, I mean that the experiment doesn't load on Pavlovia. This is usually due to some problem in the Java Script that Pavlovia is reading (since there's also no error reported) and the only thing I've changed from an experiment that does initialize is the for-loop I mentioned so I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you are looking or, right?

```js
function replaceWithdash(sentenceList, currentWordNumber) {
    const regions = sentenceList.split(",")
    const sigil = regions.map(s => s.replaceAll(/[^\s]/g, "-"))
    if (currentWordNumber !== undefined) {
        sigil.splice(currentWordNumber, 1, regions[currentWordNumber])
    }
    return sigil.join("")
}

str = "The dog, ate, the food"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str))
//"--- --- --- --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 0))
//"The dog --- --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 1))
//"--- --- ate --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 2))
// "--- --- --- the food"
```

Comment: This code does correctly display region by region, but the spaces are still considered characters, so the dashes still replace them. Now display for "The dog, ate, the food" is -------------------- with no breaks between anything. To initially have spaces between regions, I added "+ " "" to this code: result = ((result + ("-".repeat(word.length))) + " ");. But it didn't solve the spaces between words problem

Comment: If I change return sigil.join("") to return sigil.join(" ") with a space, it kinda puts a space between regions, but again its between regions defined in sentenceList, not between words.

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate the replaceAll function to ignore spaces or specific characters within regions?

Comment: It is not all dashes, spaces are maintained as spaces when hidden. If you there execute the code here in the answer itself (button `Run code snippet`), you will see the output for `"The dog, ate, the food"` fully hidden is `--- --- --- --- ----`

Comment: You're right, it works great when I just press that, but when I try ot implement it, I run into some problems. The first is that sentenceList is defined in Begin Routine (not shown here) as sentenceList = Sentence.split(",");. 'Sentence' is my column name with all the sentence strings. I tried just getting rid of that since now these sentences are being separated in the code you give, but now it's not running for some reason. I'll post the code I'm using in another comment. I'm not sure if its not working because its now in a different part of the experiment or if theres a problem in the code

Comment: function replaceWithdash(sentenceList, currentWordNumber) {
    const sentenceList = Sentence.split(",");
    const sigil = sentenceList.map(s => s.replaceAll(/[^\s]/g, "-"));
    if (currentWordNumber !== undefined) {
        sigil.splice(currentWordNumber, 1, sentenceList[currentWordNumber]);
    }
    return sigil.join("");
}

Comment: You should post a different question in this case, provided that this one is already pretty large, and this answer solves the question. If you found this answer useful, you can mark it as "accepted".

Comment: By the way, I think you have another question pretty similiar o this already, whose solution is the same. You can accept that on also

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I've accepted those answers and have made a new questions specifically about this. If anyone would like to view it, it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67713219/java-script-problem-with-initial-display-of-str-replaceall