# Java Script problem with initial display of str.replaceAll

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, logging, str-replace

I was given this code for a moving window self-paced reading experiment where the initial display is a sentence string covered by dashes (separated by word) and the display of regions (multiple words separated by `","` in the csv) is iterated as you click through the sentence. The amount of time the participant spends in a region is recorded in the output csv. Below is the code and desired display:

```
var _pj;
function replaceWithdash(Sentence, currentWordNumber) {
const sentenceList = Sentence.split(",")
const sigil = sentenceList.map(s => s.replaceAll(/[^\s]/g, "-"))
if (currentWordNumber !== undefined) {
    sigil.splice(currentWordNumber, 1, sentenceList[currentWordNumber])
}
return sigil.join("")
}
function _pj_snippets(container) {
    function in_es6(left, right) {
        if (((right instanceof Array) || ((typeof right) === "string"))) {
            return (right.indexOf(left) > (- 1));
        } else {
            if (((right instanceof Map) || (right instanceof Set) || (right instanceof WeakMap) || (right instanceof WeakSet))) {
                return right.has(left);
            } else {
                return (left in right);
            }
        }
    }
    container["in_es6"] = in_es6;
    return container;
}
_pj = {};
_pj_snippets(_pj);
Trials_Display.text = replaceWithdash(Sentence, wordNumber);
keypresses = psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys();
sentenceList = Sentence.split(",");
if ((keypresses.length > 0)) {
    if (_pj.in_es6("space", keypresses)) {
        thisResponseTime = t;
        wordNumber = (wordNumber + 1);
        if ((wordNumber < sentenceList.length)) {
            if ((wordNumber === 0)) {
                timeOfLastResponse = 0;
            }
            thisExp.addData(("IRI_" + wordNumber.toString()), (thisResponseTime - timeOfLastResponse));
            timeOfLastResponse = thisResponseTime;
            Trials_Display.text = replaceWithdash(Sentence, wordNumber);
        } else {
            continueRoutine = false;
        }
    } else {
        if (_pj.in_es6("escape", keypresses)) {
            core.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Desired Display:

```
str = "The dog, ate, the food"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str))
//"--- --- --- --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 0))
//"The dog --- --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 1))
//"--- --- ate --- ----"

console.log(replaceWithdash(str, 2))
// "--- --- --- the food"
```

Although this code does successfully show spaces between dashes and displays region by region, my problem is with the initial display of the dashed sentence. It looks like it's only showing the first two dashed regions and then once you click to reveal the words in the first region, it'll adjust to show the dashes for the third region. Also, there seems to be an extra space between regions for some reason. Something like this:

```
 str = "The dog, ate, the food"

//"--- ---  ---"

//"The dog  --- ---  ----"

//"--- ---  ate  --- ----"

// "--- ---  ---  the food"
```

I assume there's something wrong with how it's interpreting the initial string without an index (console.log(replaceWithdash(str)), but I'm not sure how to fix this, or the extra spaces.
I'm relatively new to Java script besides what I've taught myself, so any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Your function expects `sentenceList` to be an array of strings, but it's a single string. Is there something missing that calls `split(' ')`?

Comment: Please provide a runnable example.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you need to use `split(',')`

Comment: I actually just edited the post to show another line of code I had that does just that: sentenceList = Sentence.split(",");. Sorry about that!

Comment: `sentenceList = Sentence.split(",");` needs to be inside the function, and you need to change the parameter to `Sentence`

Comment: If I'm not wrong then you're asking the similar problem 3rd|4th times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680414/how-to-make-java-script-ignore-or-maintain-spaces-not-delete-them?noredirect=1#comment119628615_67680414

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for the suggestions! I did that but I still have the same problme unfortunately.

Comment: @decpk You're right, I've been working on this problem for about a week so my questions have adapted as I've learned more and tried different methods. I've accepted answers to two of those sinvce this new code deals with the problems they addressed. This is now new code with a different problem, though so that's why I ask a new question

Comment: What's the difference in this question?

Comment: So, this question has completely different code than the one I asked in the past. In fact, this code was given in an answer to those because my initial problem was the display of spaces between words when the sentence is dashed. That issue is solved. However, when using this code, I've now run into a few smaller issues. Because of this, I was advised to create a separate, more targeted question.

Comment: Since there's confusion with all the similar posts, I tried to delete one that had the same answer as another, but Stack exchange won't let me. :(

Comment: I just executed the code you provided and for `replaceWithdash("The dog, ate, the food")` I get exatly the desired result: `"--- --- --- --- ----"`. What is the issue again?

Comment: I've edited and added all the code in the Each Frame tab of the JS code component in the Psychopy experiment, not just the replaceWithdash function. Maybe there's something wrong there then?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, TLDR the comments. Here's how I'd do it:

```
function replaceWithDash(input,partNumber) {
    //First, lets check if partNumber was omitted, since we can use this case
    //to replace a single part as well
    if(typeof partNumber!="number")
        //Just remove the commas and replace every letter with the dash
        return input.replace(/,/g,"").replace(/[^\s]/g,"-");

    //If partNumber was specified (the function didn't end on the previous return), lets split the sentence
    parts=input.split(",");
    //remove the partNumber-th element and replace it with its dashed version
    parts.splice(partNumber,1,replaceWithdash(parts[partNumber]));
    //then join everything again and fix repeating spaces (it's quicker to do this once here than trimming each element)
    return parts.join(" ").replace(/[\s]+/g," ");
}
```

Note that I fixed the function name.